# Calling Static Method of Class WITHOUT classname, PHP

Tags: php, structured-programming

Maybe it's foolish question, And I want to implement some utils functions using OOP in PHP, instead SP (Strudtured Programming), but with uses like SP.

An example:

```
class A {
  public static function x() {
    echo "using x method!";
  }
}
```

According to Static OOP, to use the x function I need to use:

```
A::x();
```

But I want to use only:

```
x();
```

How can do it?
Thk

Comment: "Static OOP", as such, is a conflicted term.

Comment: What if there are two classes that both have `x` method, which one should run?

Comment: Im not sure why you would want to do that? if that's the case just write a normal procedural function..

Answer (score 2):

```
function x() {
   return A::x();
}
```

Or you can even try to do:

```
function x() {
    return A::__FUNCTION__();
}
```